# Send Multipal row date overs same in email address in one mail

Tags: java

I have Inventor google sheet . There are multiple Email addressee. and Items , but Same item we purchased form same vendor, i want a script ,which can send multiple items requirement for same vendor email notification in one mail

Comment: Have you tried something?